# ASP.NET: Storing Repeater Value in Session

Tags: asp.net, session, repeater

I want to store the value of a databound repeat to a session state.

This is my code so far:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
<h1 id="price" class="QPrice">$<%# Eval("Price")%></h1>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind"

```
Session("Qprice") = ?
```

How do I retrive the value of the h1 element or retrive a specific value of SqlDatasource1, from the codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

Session("Qprice"+ID) = (decimal)drv.Row["Price"]; 
In the end you will have all prices in session, and you can access by the id's of the data that has bound to the list. But you are storing information that you have access.

Answer (score 0):

In the repeater1 define the object DatakeyNames="Price" and specify the Item Data Bound event
then in code behind

```
protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
                          || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    { 
        Button b = e.Item.FindControl("myButton") as Button;  
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView; 
        Session("Qprice") = (decimal)drv.Row["Price"];
    } 
}
```

Here you can save the value or do whatever you want with price.

Comment: the problem i see occurring is since this is a repeater, if there are 15 items the session variable will only hold the last one

Answer (score 0):

I would store it to strongly type List first and store it in Session

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Dim repeaterItems As New List(Of Decimal)()

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim b As Button = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("myButton"), Button)
        Dim drv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)


        repeaterItems.Add(CDec(drv.Row("Price")))
    End If


    Session("Qprice") = repeaterItems
End Sub
```

So I can access it again later like

```
Dim repeaterItemsFromSession As List(Of Decimal) = DirectCast(Session("Qprice"), List(Of Decimal))
```